# Parentheses around a constant or around a cast expression involving a constant

Tags: c, parentheses

From time to time I see this code:

```
#define X1   (13)
#define X2   ((size_t)13)
```

As I understand, the (outer) `()` are redundant here. Is that correct?

---

UPD: Some software development guidelines may require it.

For example:
MISRA C:2004, Rule 19.4 (required):

> C macros shall only expand to a braced initialiser, a constant, a **parenthesised expression**, a type qualifier, a storage class specifier, or a do-while-zero construct.

However, MISRA C:2012 has:

```
#define MY_NULL_2 ( void * ) 0
#define sqrt( x ) ( _BUILTIN_sqrt ( x ) )
```

Comment: For `X1`: yes, it's redundant. For `X2`, they limit the scope of the cast to _just_ the `13`

Comment: Redundant parentheses can never hurt.

Comment: @Barmar: C 2018 5.2.4.1 1 says they can hurt; an implementation is allowed to break if you have more than 63 nested parentheses.

Comment: Redundant parenthese can *practically* never hurt.

Comment: `(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((X1 + 3) * ...)` would break some implementations

Comment: @EricPostpischil Compiling `limits-exprparen.c` from GCC's testsuite using GCC leads to `gcc: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault signal terminated program cc1`, while using Clang leads to `fatal error: bracket nesting level exceeded maximum of 256`, while using MSVC leads to `fatal error C1026: parser stack overflow, program too complex`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe the first example needs parentheses, but always parenthesizing macro bodies is a reasonable habit.

The second one will produce unexpected grouping if you remove the outer parentheses from the definition and then invoke it in the context `X2[a]`.

Comment: Although `X2[a]` would be a strange thing to write. I know that if `a` is an array it's equivalent to `a[X2]`, but no one ever actually takes advantage of that equivalence.

Comment: A really cool answer would reference to the current standard and reason about necessity. ;-) "_I think ..._" is a bit suspicious.

Comment: @busybee: despite the risk of being uncool, I don't feel inclined to spend the time proving unnecessary an idiom which I think is reasonable. If your suspicion is that I'm lazy, then guilty as charged.

Comment: Re: "invoke it in the context `X2[a]`": thanks! I've searched a context in which removal of the outer parentheses will produce unexpected grouping. As I see: all the operators with precedence higher than precedence of cast operator are potential candidates. However, it seems that only subscript operator is the valid one.

Answer (score 1):

> As I understand, the (outer) () are redundant here. Is that correct?

In the first case, `(13)` can cause a problem. See below.
In the the 2nd case `((size_t)13)` tends to prevent problems as it insures the cast (which does not have top [order of precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)) is applied to only `13` and not some following code.

---

The `()` in `#define X1 (13)` have a disadvantage.  Consider *stringification*.

As `(80)`, the incorrect format string is formed.

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)
#define BUFFER_LEN_WITH (80)
#define BUFFER_LEN_WITHOUT 80

// Could have used either BUFFER_LEN_WITH, BUFFER_LEN_WITHOUT here.
#define BUFFER_SIZE (BUFFER_LEN_WITHOUT + 1) 

int main(void) {
  char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
  printf("Format: <%s>\n", "%" TOSTRING( BUFFER_LEN_WITH) "s");
  printf("Format: <%s>\n", "%" TOSTRING( BUFFER_LEN_WITHOUT) "s");
  int count = scanf("%" TOSTRING( BUFFER_LEN_WITHOUT) "s", buffer);
  if (count == 1) {
    printf("<%s>\n", buffer);
  }
}
```

Output

```
Format: <%(80)s>  <-- Wrong format
Format: <%80s>
zvxcx
<zvxcx>
```